# UITextView Character Wrapping

Tags: ios, swift

I think I'm missing something here. Create a run of mill single view app in Xcode. Add a `UITextView` in the `Main.storyboard`, hook up an `IBOutlet` to the provided `ViewController` and in `viewDidLoad` set the `textContainer` `lineBreakMode` to `.byCharWrapping`. Run the app and the provided text is still word wrapping. Tried in `viewDidAppear` still word wrapping. Created a side process that add characters to the text view on the main thread, and also set `lineBreakMode` to character wrapping, still word wrapping.

**Note**
I did find that `attributeText` with `NSParagraphStyle` `lineBreakMode` set to `.byCharWrapping` does work, and setting text there after keeps the character wrapping. I would like a solution for just setting the `textContainer` `lineBreakMode` rather than, what it feels like, a hack.

Comment: If you want character wrapping in a `UITextView`, you can either do it (as you found) via attributed text, or... it looks like you'd need to create and manage your own `NSTextContainer` and `NSLayoutManager`. My assumption is that `UITextView` has enough "going on behind the scenes" that simply setting `lineBreakMode` on its `textContainer` gets overridden.

Comment: Just to add to this, I checked to see if the `textContainer` `lineBreakMode` property was being set elsewhere, and I found that wasn't happening. But interestingly properties like `lineFragmentPadding` are being adhered to.